# How can I access command line arguments indexed from the end?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

How can I get second argument from the end of arguments line in bash?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853946/getting-the-last-argument-passed-to-a-shell-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way in Bash

```
set -- ${@:(-2)}
echo $1
```

or simply

```
echo ${@:(-2):1}
```

Comment: @Dennis, thks for the comment

Answer (score 4):

To print the second last argument use:

```
echo "${@:(-2):1}"
```