# bash: How do I identify the filename argument among arguments passed from the command line?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line-arguments

I know if I have a command `./run -c -p '$' -s 10 file.txt`
I can write bash script like this

```
while read line; do 
   # ...
done < $6
```

But what if the command may or may not have one/some options, maybe look like this

`./run -p '$' -s 10 file.txt`

or this

`./run '$' -s 10 file.txt`

Then how can I get the file name in the script?

Comment: Note that your last snippet is nonstandard in that most (POSIX-compliant) utilities expect _all_ option arguments _before_ the non-option (filename) ones; in other words: most utilities would interpret _all 3 arguments_ in your last snippet as non-option (filename) arguments.

Answer (score 3):

If the file name *always* comes at the end of the list of arguments, you can use `"${@: -1}"` to select the last argument. Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1854031/3565972

Eg.:

```
while read line; do 
   ...
done < "${@: -1}"
```

Comment: You need the space, otherwise the `:-` gets interpreted as "default value of 1".

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for catching that!

Comment: May I know what if my filename is not at the end of the list of arguments? Than what should I refer to that filename? Thanks.

Comment: @LuckyLast If you don't know the position of your filename, you can either pick it out of the arguments using something like a regex (eg. search for a string that looks like `*.txt`); you could use a flag to specify that a filename follows (eg. `-f file.txt`); or you could go with a robust method like `getopts` as [suggested by user2303197](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23861378/3565972)

Comment: @savanto, Thank you for your response. but what if the command like this : ./run filename -c -p '$' -s 10, that getopts doesn't working on it.

Comment: @LuckyLast Actually, it looks like `getopts` will stop processing options if they are not a flag that looks like `-x`. So I think the simplest way would be to use `getopts` and add an option `-f` which would precede your filename. You can use the `getopts` solution provided by user2303197, add a `-f` case, and get the filename from `$OPTARG`. Then your call would be `./run -f filename -c -p '$' -s 10`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `getopts` to process the options (that also allows them to be in arbitrary order):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts cp:s: option; do
    case $option in
    c)
        echo "-c used"
        ;;
    p)
        echo "-p used with argument $OPTARG"
        ;;
    s)
        echo "-s used with argument $OPTARG"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "unknown option used"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done

shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ));

echo "Arguments left after options processing: $@"
```

Now if you run this:

```
$ ./test.sh -c -p '$' -s 10 file.txt
-c used
-p used with argument $
-s used with argument 10
Arguments left after options processing: file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the filename in your script ./run. Then you can just use $# to get the total of the parameters.
And so you can write as below:

```
eval filename=\$$#
```

If you just want to get the filename from a line like this:  ./run ** ** ** ** file.txt

You can just use awk as below:

```
line="./run ** ** ** ** file.txt"
echo $line | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Good Luck!