# assign last positional parameter to variable and remove it from "$@"

Tags: shell, command-line, sh

In my `/bin/sh` script, I need to pass an indeterminate number of positional parameters, and get the last one (assign the last one to variable `$LAST`) and then remove this last argument from `$@`

For example, I call my script with 4 arguments:

```
./myscript.sh AAA BBB CCC DDD
```

And inside my script, I need to echo the following:

```
echo $LAST
DDD

echo $@
AAA BBB CCC
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the last argument passed to a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853946/getting-the-last-argument-passed-to-a-shell-script)

Comment: @l0b0 - no, it does not. Those solutions only work in bash.

Comment: @400theCat, Re *"...only work in bash"*:   correction -- **some** of the 28 answers to [*Getting the last argument passed to a shell script*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853946/getting-the-last-argument-passed-to-a-shell-script) are `bash` only, but some of the other answers are for *POSIX* shells.

Comment: @agc However, that question does not ask how to remove the last positional parameter.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to simply change your script to take `DDD` as the first argument, followed by `AAA`, `BBB`, and `CCC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop to move all arguments except the last to the end of positional parameters list; so that the last becomes the first, could be referred to by `$1`, and could be removed from the list using `shift`.

```
#!/bin/sh -
count=0
until test $((count+=1)) -ge $#
do
  set -- "$@" "$1"
  shift
done

LAST=${1-}
shift $((!!$#))

echo "$LAST"
echo "$@"
```