# In bash how to use the last argument- and adding all other arguments to array

Tags: bash, sum, integer-arithmetic, positional-parameter

I have a script where the user can add as many arguments as he would like (numbers).

The script will sum all the numbers beside the last number - The last number (argument) is the number that I need to divide by

For example:

```
./test.sh 2 2 6 5
```

This will sum the first 3 numbers (2+2+6) and divide the answer by 5 (the last argument)

1. How can I use the last argument?  Echo ????
2. How can I move loop the first arguments besides the last one – I would like that all 3 arguments will be added to an array and I can loop it
3. Please note that the number of arguments can be changed

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853946/getting-the-last-argument-passed-to-a-shell-script/26506164#26506164) cover what you're trying to do?

Comment: echo $@| awk '{ sum = 0; for(i=1;i<$(NF);i++){ sum += i } print sum/$NF }'

Answer (score 0):

### Shortly (with *bashisms*)

As this question is tagged [integer-arithmetic](/questions/tagged/integer-arithmetic) and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

Here is a small and efficient script:

```
#!/bin/bash

addVals=${*: 1 : $# - 1}
declare -i intResult=" ( ${addVals// /+} ) / ${@: -1} "
echo $intResult
```

But there's no *loop*...

### Long answer

> How can I use the last argument? Echo ????

You could **make your tries** in command line:

```
set -- 2 2 6 5
```

Then

```
echo $@
2 2 6 5

echo ${*: 3}
6 5

echo ${*: -1} 
5

echo ${*: 1 : -1} 
bash:  -1: substring expression < 0

echo $#  
4
echo ${*: 1 : $# -1}
2 2 6
```

Ok, then

```
someVar=${*: 1 : $# -1}
echo ${someVar// /:SpaceReplacment:}
2:SpaceReplacment:2:SpaceReplacment:6
```

so

```
declare -i result
result=" ( ${someVar// /+} ) / ${*: -1} "
echo $result
2
```

> How can I move loop the first arguments besides the last one – I would like that all 3 arguments will be added to an array and I can loop it

Still forward, under command line...

```
someArray=("${@: 1: $# -1 }")
```

Use `declare -p` to show *`$someArray`*'s content:

```
declare -p someArray
```

```
declare -a someArray=([0]="2" [1]="2" [2]="6")
```

Then

```
declare -i mySum=0
for i in "${someArray[@]}";do
    mySum+=i
done
echo $mySum
10

echo $(( mySum / ${*: -1} ))
2
```

> Please note that the number of arguments can be changed

Please note:

- Using **double quotes** allow processing of strings containing spaces:

  ```
  set -- foo bar 'foo bar baz'
  echo ${2}
  bar
  echo ${*: $# }
  foo bar baz
  ```
- Difference betweeen use of "$@" (array to array) and "$*" (array to string)

  ```
  set -- foo bar 'foo bar' 'foo bar baz'
  ```

  If I take 3 first elements:

  ```
  someArray=("${@: 1: $# -1 }")
  declare -p someArray
  declare -a someArray=([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="foo bar")
  ```

  But

  ```
  someArray=("${*: 1: $# -1 }")
  declare -p someArray
  declare -a someArray=([0]="foo bar foo bar")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use the last argument? Echo ????

Granting `$# > 0`, you can use `"${!#}"`.

> How can I move loop the first arguments besides the last one – I would
> like that all 3 arguments will be added to an array and I can loop it

Again granting `$# > 0`, you can refer to `"${@:1:$# - 1}"`.

Read the Arrays section in the bash manual to know how to properly expand arrays.

I also recommend learning how quoting works and knowing the dangers of unwanted word splitting and globbing.

Answer (score 0):

There are about a thousand ways of doing this. As you would like to make use of integer arithmetic, you can do the following in bash

A short semi-cryptic version would be:

```
IFS=+
echo $(( ( ${*} - ${#:-1} ) / ${#:-1} ))
```

Here we make use of the difference between `"${*}"` and `"${#}"` to perform the sum by setting `IFS=+` (See [What is the difference between "$@" and "$*" in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3008695/8344060))

A long classic approach would be:

```
for i in "$@"; do ((s+=i)); done
echo $(( (s-${@:-1})/${@:-1} ))
```

It's easier to sum all terms and subtract the last term afterwards