# rename a dir making sure it doesn't exist already

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, mv

I was wondering about following

Let's say you have two directory's in linux dir1 and dir2. now when I do

```
mv dir1 dir2
```

then dir1 gets moved into dir2.

But what if I want to rename dir1 into dir2? And while dir2 already exist, let bash tell me so and ask me if I wish to override? or maybe just tell me that it can't be renamed for it already exists?

Is there a way for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make mv create the directory to be moved to if it doesn't exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547719/is-there-a-way-to-make-mv-create-the-directory-to-be-moved-to-if-it-doesnt-exis)

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is, use `i` and `T` options.

`T` will think the target as normal file, so that won't do "move into" if target dir existed; `i` will let you confirm. In your case, it would be:

```
mv -iT dir1 dir2
```

If `dir2` doesn't exists, no confirmation message will show.

Note, if target dir2 is not empty, you cannot mv, even though you confirmed.

If you want to overwrite anyway, you need write a little function/script to do it.

Comment: Thank, this is the solution to my wondering :p . That dir2 can't be renamed when not empty makes sense too, for then it would not only rename but also make a join of the files. I guess this is not in the power of this command?

Comment: @boselfje you can write function/script check if the target exits, if true, ask confirmation, recieve 'y', do something like `mv dir1/* dir2` then rename dir2 -> dir1. of course you have to handle the existing sub-dirs if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `mv` with option `i` it will prompt and check do you prefer to overwrite an existing directory or not if it is existing.

If  `dir1` and `dir2` exists and you try as follows it will prompt you. If dir2 is not existing it will not prompt.

```
mv -i dir1 dir2
```

Comment: this is not the correct answer. perhaps you didn't understand the requirement.