# How build a react project inside build folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I do: `npm run build` I would like to create a folder inside the build folder and move all build output inside that folder.

At this moment I'm doing this:

```
"prebuild": "npm run build:clean",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"postbuild": "mkdir dest && cp -r build/* dest && npm run build:clean && mv dest build",
"build:clean": "rimraf build/*",
```

1. Clear build folder
2. Build app
3. Create dest folder
4. Copy all that is inside in build folder in dest folder
5. Clear build folder
6. Move dest folder inside build folder

How can I reduce it?

Comment: You can do this easily if you build your application using webpack

Comment: mmmm.. I'm new with react.. can you help me?

Comment: Sure, try this link https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/getting-started-with-react-js-using-webpack-and-babel-66549f8fbcb8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is: **you can't change it**.

Build output is fixed in `create-react-app` and can't be changed, and this decision has its roots in philosophy of CRA.

[Citing Dan Abramov, co-author of create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1354#issuecomment-301769782):

> I don’t think it is strange this feature is missing. Largely, it is intentional. It ensures most people have similar setups, and people can build tools (e.g. for deployment) assuming the same directory structure.

However, you can use [trick backed-up by him](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1354#issuecomment-299956790), which is using `mv` to move `build` output:

```
"build": "react-scripts build && mv build {YOUR_PATH}"
```

Comment: but first I need create the folder to move build to my path, no?

Comment: You can create directory if it doesn't exist already, for example using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547927/7059945).