# I am trying to move a directory in my downloads to the python site-packages but it says that the directory doesn't exist

Tags: python

I am trying to instal `LightAquaBlue` and I need to move the `LightAquaBlue` directory to the python site-packages.

When I run it in the terminal I get this:

```
$ mv ~/Downloads/LightAquaBlue ~/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
mv: rename /Users/Pau/Downloads/LightAquaBlue to /Users/Pau/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages: No such file or directory
```

Any idea how I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make mv create the directory to be moved to if it doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547719/is-there-a-way-to-make-mv-create-the-directory-to-be-moved-to-if-it-doesnt-exis)

Comment: Either "LightAquaBlue" does not exist in Downloads, or your Python path is not valid.  Where did you get the Python path?

Comment: BTW, it's not normal workflow to install packages manually like this -- usually one uses tools like `pip`